# Mokito not working with Jersey and Jetty while running JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jetty, mockito

When testing Jersey REST `OrderResource` it returns empty `List<Order> orders`. Mockito part seems to be working incorrectly since it's accessing database layer. How to fix it?

**Test**

```
 public class OrderResourceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Mock
    private OrderService orderServiceMock;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        //database set up
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(OrderResource.class);

        return resourceConfig;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetOrders() {
        when(orderServiceMock.findOrders()).thenReturn(getMockOrders());

        Response response = target("/orders")
            .request()
            .get();
        List < Order > orders = response.readEntity(new GenericType < List < Order >> () {});
        assertEquals("Should return status 200", 200, response.getStatus());
        assertTrue(orders.size() == 1); // orders.size() is 0. Why?
    }


    private List < Order > getMockOrders() {
        Customer customer = new Customer(1 L, "CompanyName", "Street", "123456", "City", "UK");
        List < OrderLine > orderLines = Arrays.asList(new OrderLine(1 L, "s345664lkdLDSDf", "Samsung Galaxy 4", 1));
        Order order = new Order(1 L, customer, orderLines);

        return Arrays.asList(order);
    }
}
```

This [project](https://github.com/Robert-Leggett/jersey_restful_webservice/blob/master/src/test/java/au/com/example/api/CustomerResourceTest.java) was used as a reference

Comment: Where do you instruct your system under test to use `orderServiceMock` rather than your production OrderService?

Comment: In the current test, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The key part you're missing from the example is the [`InjectableProvider`](https://github.com/Robert-Leggett/jersey_restful_webservice/blob/master/src/test/java/au/com/example/api/CustomerResourceTest.java#L118-L140):

```
class InjectableProvider extends AbstractBinder implements Factory<CustomerService> {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindFactory(this).to(CustomerService.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }

    public CustomerService provide() {
        return serviceMock;
    }

    public void dispose(CustomerService service) {
        serviceMock = null;
    }
}
```

It's the provider's job to inject the mock into the resource. If you follow the same approach and customise it for your `OrderService`, your mock should be invoked.

Make sure you register it during configuration:

```
config.register(new InjectableProvider());
```